# how to solve captcha

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver           
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import csv
import requests
from csv import writer


 
url="https://allegro.pl/oferta/lurlego-76900-speed-champions-koenigsegg-jesko-11096977887"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    
driver.get(url)

        
try:
    title=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="msub_k4"]//h4').text
except:
    pass
print(title)
```

How to solve that will scraping the data  any solution for it....is there any possible solution for that kindly recommend me any solution...
[image]

Comment: personal experience is that you better go with proxies. Once you are at that stage, your IP is recorded and it will be locked at a later stage....

Comment: how we use proxies with selenium.....any solution you suggest me....

Comment: just type it on google, or on their doc. you will need to find a proxy provider etc. some are free, but do not always work.